# Devise: how can i get default_url_options to work as instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i have an application which sets some stuff in default_url_options as instance method.

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  added_options = { locale: I18n.locale }
  added_options[:root] = params[:root].present? ? params[:root] : nil
  options.merge(added_options)
end
```

devise however only works with default_url_options set as class method. as you can see i have to access params and thats not available as class method.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:--Redirect-with-locale-after-authentication-failure

any idea how to fix this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm using a routes hack to get it working...

```
get "/users/sign_in" => redirect("/en/users/sign_in")
```

made `:locale` optional in routes.
this way i can use `default_url_options` as instance method.